# Session variable better than static variable considering performance? If not, what is the solution?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, static, session-variables

I was using static variables in few of my screens. Seeing this, I was advised by my senior not to use them as they hinder performance. FYI, I am working on **MVC** application.

What I got as an alternative is using Session variable. But I am not sure about using it instead for which I want your advise. Is Session variable the right choice or not? If not, what is the better option.
Please suggest.

Comment: What are you storing in the variables, is the data stored per user or per application?

Comment: Data stored is an integer. Its scope is within a controller.

Comment: @Nitish: If its scope is within a controller, then why are you storing it in a static?

Comment: Because there are various actions during the cycle. for example Search, Remove after which the page is reloaded.

Comment: Session content is effectively (if not actually) static already.  Both are means of having effectively global state, and both should only be used when you are actually storing information that need to be global, rather than something you just don't want to bother scoping locally.

Comment: For this kind of very temporary data you could look at using `TempData`

Comment: @Servy : Ok. How should I proceed here?

Comment: @Nitish Given that we have no idea what you're actually storing we don't know how it should be properly handled.  It may be that a static variable is actually appropriate, or it may be that you should be passing the state to the page (in some hidden form value) and then back on each request.  We don't have enough details to really help you.

Comment: @RobWhite : Will TempData persist my data?

Comment: @Servy : I am storing integer value.

Comment: @Nitish That doesn't help in the least.  We need to know what it's actually used for, when you need it, how it's generated, when it will be used, how long you need to hold onto it, whether or not it can be re-generated at all, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Knowing very little how you are using this variable, I'd say stay away from static variables not because of performance but mostly because of concurrency. Using session variables will guarantee isolation for each user, unless you do want values to be shared across users.

Performance wise static variables will be faster simply because there is no need to serialize them to and from session (less much so if you are using in process session management.)

Comment: I was not aware of that. Thanks.

Comment: A good example of something you might actually want to store as a static variable is a synchronization mechanism.  If you need to synchronize access to...something, you may need a static `object` to `lock` on.  That would be an example of an appropriate use of `static` (although one you'd still want to avoid if possible).

Comment: @Servy - he is using it for an int value so that would not be appropriate for locking.

Comment: @OtávioDécio Correct, I'm just giving one example (clearly not applicable here) in which you may prefer a static variable over session content.  In the OP's case he may not want either; we have no way of knowing.

Comment: That's very true, there is very little information in the question. I just find it hard to justify using static for performance alone, I can't see where that would be an issue for a single integer variable.